# What would make a native library not open with Java 8 but open with Java 6?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I'm using JNI to run native code on my Java application. Currently the application runs with Java 6, but I would like to start running it with Java 8 so I could use more APIs. However, I'm having a problem in which one shared library simply does not open. When I do System.loadLibrary it finds the file but it hangs out indefinitely. It loads normally with Java 6.

Unfortunately I don't have access to the source code of the shared library so I can't try to build it again.

Thank you for your attention,
Best regards

**EDIT:**

The library has an expensive initialization because it loads heavy files. The native interface has five functions.

I runned the program with -version:jni parameter and found out that it is hanging during a function link. The last JNI log was:

[Dynamic-linking native method *method-name* ... JNI]

The signature of this method is:

```
protected native long *method-name*(int, double, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, double, int[], double, double, double, double, double, int)
```

I'm using jdk1.6.0_45 and jdk1.8.0_151 for x86 systems.

This issues happens in Linux, but not in Windows (there is a version o the library compiled for Windows too).

Comment: Need more information. How much functions are in there? How are they registered from the library's side? Does it do some long operation during init? What are system configurations? Basically, there's a lot of moving parts to just give blanket answers that are "good enough for most".

Comment: Please describe your platform and JRE

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I edited the question trying to give more information.

Comment: We often call System.loadLibrary from a static class constructor. It is easy, as long as it works without glitches. To isolate your problem, I would start with loading the native implementation library from a background thread, possibly after some delay that will reduce the risk of interference with loading of the Java app.

Comment: What operating system(s) are you using?  You need to find out where your process is getting hung, and the tools to do that depend on the operating system you're running on.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm using Linux. I edited the question with more information. Thank you!

Comment: @Eduardo You can use `pstack PID` to get the call stack(s) for all the threads the JVM is running.  That would probably give you a lot of information as to what's going on.  If you're running on RH/Centos, `pstack` should give you the call stack for every thread in the process.  If not, you may have to use `gstack`.